# Swift 2 AVAudioSession setCategory extra argument 'error'

Tags: ios, swift2

When I set up  to record audio, I get an error.

```
if (session.respondsToSelector("requestRecordPermission:")) {
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
        if granted {
            print("granted")
            session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)
            session.setActive(true, error: nil)
            self.recorder ()
        } else{
            print("not granted")
        }
   })
}
```

[image]

Why do I get an error for having `error: nil`?

Comment: Because in Swift 2 there is no `error:` any more. You should read about Swift 2 before you try to use it; things have really changed a lot!

Comment: You might even want to (gasp!) read my book! http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_throwing_and_catching_errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
```

Let's see if you can figure out for yourself, from that model, how to fix the next line...